# Can you reset the Azure MSDN Credits so I can use another account?

Tags: azure, msdn

I used my work account when activating the Azure Credits I get with my MSDN subscription.

Turns out, as I don't have Active Directory admin permissions, I can't register apps etc. This makes it pretty useless. I'm not likely to get the required permissions either.

I'm not convinced creating a new directory and then following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription is applicable. I don't want to move my work account to another Directory as there are other subscriptions I need access to.

Is there a way to cancel/reset/something else this subscription and start again? I'd like to use a personal/new account.

Comment: Have you tried creating another directory? Your work account belongs to the default one, which is controlled by your work.

Comment: I'm not able to create another directory due to lack of permissions. I'll hopefully be able to get someone who can to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reach out to Azure Billing/Subscription Support. They migrated a Visual Studio/MSDN Subscription for me to another Tenant/Account in the past and should be able to help here.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/

Billing and subscription management support is available to all Azure customers - so you won't need a support plan for it ;-)

Comment: This ended up working. Took a while with the requirement to have another sub (PAYG) on the destination. But it worked.